# 2 EISA Configurations

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I want to create more partitions on my hard drive, but it won't let me as I have to many already (C Drive, D Drive, and 2 EISA Configurations).

I want to keep the back-up of the OS but is there need for the 2? And can I delete one?
If so, which one?

EISA 1: 10.74GB
EISA 2: 3.26

I presume the 2nd one?

Answer (score 0):

EISA partitions are OEM utility or recovery partitions, and I would not recommend deleting them blindly (or at all). I guess if you have a full disk image backup then you can get rid of them to reclaim space, but I advise you to just leave them alone.

If you only want to get rid of them so you can create more partitions, there's no need. While [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) partitioned disks can have up to 4 primary partitions, they can also have an [extended partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Boot_Record) (so 3 primary and 1 extended is possible) inside which you can create as many logical partitions as required.

Of course, newer [GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) disks can have up to 128 "primary" partitions.